# What does Some() do on the left hand side of a variable assignment?

Tags: syntax, rust, pattern-matching

I was reading some Rust code and I came across this line

```
if let Some(path) = env::args().nth(1) {
```

Inside of this function

```
fn main() {
    if let Some(path) = env::args().nth(1) {
        // Try reading the file provided by the path.
        let mut file = File::open(path).expect("Failed reading file.");
        let mut content = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut content);

        perform_conversion(content.as_str()).expect("Conversion failed.");
    } else {
        println!(
            "provide a path to a .cue file to be converted into a MusicBrainz compatible tracklist."
        )
    }
}
```

The line seems to be assigning the `env` argument to the variable path but I can't work out what the `Some()` around it is doing.

I took a look at the documentation for [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and I understand how it works when used on the right hand side of `=` but on the left hand side I am a little confused.

Am I right in thinking this line is equivalent to

```
if let path = Some(env::args().nth(1)) {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/expressions/if-expr.html#if-let-expressions) :

> An if let expression is semantically similar to an if expression but
>   in place of a condition expression it expects the keyword let followed
>   by a refutable pattern, an = and an expression. If the value of the
>   expression on the right hand side of the = matches the pattern, the
>   corresponding block will execute, otherwise flow proceeds to the
>   following else block if it exists. Like if expressions, if let
>   expressions have a value determined by the block that is evaluated.

In here the important part is **refutability**. What it means refutable pattern in here it can be in different forms. For example :

```
enum Test {
    First(String, i32, usize),
    Second(i32, usize),
    Third(i32),
}
```

You can check the x's value for a value for 3 different pattern like :

```
fn main() {
    let x = Test::Second(14, 55);
    if let Test::First(a, b, c) = x {}
    if let Test::Second(a, b) = x {} //This block will be executed
    if let Test::Third(a) = x {}
}
```

This is called **refutability**. But consider your code like this:

```
enum Test {
    Second(i32, usize),
}

fn main() {
    let x = Test::Second(14, 55);
    if let Test::Second(a, b) = x {}
}
```

This code will not compile because x's pattern is obvious, it has single pattern. 
You can get more information from the [reference of refutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html#refutability-whether-a-pattern-might-fail-to-match).

Also you are not right thinking for this:

```
if let path = Some(env::args().nth(1)) {
```

Compiler will throw error like **irrefutable if-let pattern** because as the reference says: "keyword let followed by a refutable pattern". In here there is no refutable pattern after "let". Actually this code tries to create a variable named path which is an Option and this make no sense because there is no "**If**" needed,

Instead Rust expects from you to write like this:

```
let path = Some(env::args().nth(1)); // This will be seem like Some(Some(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers go into a lot of detail, which might be more than you need to know.

Essentially, this:

```
if let Some(path) = env::args().nth(1) {
    // Do something with path
} else {
    // otherwise do something else
}
```

is *identical* to this:

```
match env::args().nth(1) {
    Some(path) => { /* Do something with path */ }
    _          => { /* otherwise do something else */ }
}
```