# How do you cast a Rust variant enum to an underlying struct?

Tags: rust

The `bind()` call below works for IPV4, but not for IPV6.

```
pub enum SocketAddr {
    V4(SocketAddrV4),
    V6(SocketAddrV6),
}

pub fn new<A: ToSocketAddrs>(local_addr: A, _: Option<u32>) -> io::Result<UdpConnector> {
    let mut addr = net::addr_from_trait(local_addr)?;
    debug!("Attempting to connect to {:?}", addr);
    UdpSocket::bind(addr).expect(&format!("Couldn't bind to address {:?}", addr))
}
```

I think that I need to set the `scope_id` for the `SocketAddrV6`. However, I don't have a `SocketAddrV6`, I only have a generic `SocketAddr`, which doesn't implement `scope_id()`.

I can call `is_ipv6()` on that `SocketAddr`, in order to see what type it is. If it's IPV6, then in C language terms, I would like to cast to the underlying `SocketAddrV6`, so I can call `set_scope_id()` on it. Then I want to pass the resulting `SocketAddr` or `SocketAddrV6` variable to `bind()`.

### What I have tried

The following apparently only works on primitive types:

```
let addr2 = addr as SocketAddrV6
```

If I try to do implicit conversion, I get a type mismatch error. I guess it's telling me that `addr` is an enum, not a `SocketAddrV6` struct. I know that. How do I do a cast in Rust?

```
54 |             let addr2: SocketAddrV6 = addr; 
   |                        ------------   ^^^^ expected struct `std::net::SocketAddrV6`, found enum `std::net::SocketAddr`
```

And here is another conversion attempt. Same error.

```
55 |             let addr2 = SocketAddr::V6(addr);
   |                                        ^^^^ expected struct `std::net::SocketAddrV6`, found enum `std::net::SocketAddr`
```

Another try

```
    error[E0573]: expected type, found variant `SocketAddr::V6`
  --> src/net/connector.rs:52:33
   |
52 |             let addr2 = addr as SocketAddr::V6;
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a type
```

Edit: Based on @Lukas solution, the following seems to compile, but I don't yet know whether it is doing what I want.

```rust
let mut addr2 = if let SocketAddr::V6(c) = addr {c} else { unreachable!() };
addr2.set_scope_id(2);
```

Comment: Or this? [Unwrap inner type when enum variant is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953711/unwrap-inner-type-when-enum-variant-is-known)

Comment: I encourage you to re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), especially the [chapter on enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html). These Rust fundamentals are well-covered by existing material.

Comment: @Lukas, I had seen your solution, but you didn't actually explain the syntax, and I couldn't wrap my brain around it. I tried again today, and I think I have something which appears to be working, although I still don't understand the syntax.

Comment: I have spent hours trying to figure this out, googling and trying various solutions. I have by no means posted everything I tried. To have this closed is extremely frustrating. I appreciate @Lukas responding, although I had already seen his solution when I posted this question.

Comment: This was a waste of my time.

Comment: @PaulStone don't consider this as a waste of time, maybe your next question should be why this syntax works? Please check, I wrote an answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901550/what-does-some-do-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-variable-assignment/53902304#53902304, if you still have questions after reading please ask, good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @Omer. I appreciate the response. That's a nice explanation. Additionally, I did get some help in another forum, and confirmation that my syntax (derived from Lukas' solution) is a reasonable approach.