# Type casting for Option type

Tags: rust, casting, type-conversion

I'm newbie in Rust from Python. I believe it's a basic question, but I am too new to find the answer by keywords like **Type Casting Option**.

In Python, to make the type checker know return type is not `Optional[int] + int`, we can address `assert` logic to enforce the type checker know `x` will never be `None` after line `assert`.

```py
from typing import Optional


def add_one(x: Optional[int] = None) -> int:
    if x is None:
        x = 0
    assert x is not None
    return x + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_one(0)    # 1
    add_one()     # 1
    add_one(999)  # 1000
```

In Rust, assuming the interface is same, how do achieve the same thing? Namely, how to make compiler know the type of `x` is not `Option` anymore?

```rust
fn add_one(mut x: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    if x == None {
        x = Some(0);
    }
    return x + 1;
}

fn main() {
    add_one(Some(0));
    add_one(None);
    add_one(Some(999));
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `std::option::Option<i32>`
 --> tmp.rs:5:14
  |
5 |     return x + 1;
  |            - ^ - {integer}
  |            |
  |            std::option::Option<i32>
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `std::option::Option<i32>`
```

Note that I've tried things like adding another variable with type i32 (`let y: i32 = x;`), but it didn't work either with following message.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> tmp.rs:5:22
  |
5 |     let y: i32 = x;
  |                  ^ expected i32, found enum `std::option::Option`
  |
  = note: expected type `i32`
             found type `std::option::Option<i32>`
```

Comment: The solutions are in the answers but if you want to go in detail and see how rust treats an `Option` in general, you can check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901550/what-does-some-do-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-variable-assignment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or):

```
fn add_one(x: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    x.unwrap_or(0) + 1
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(1, add_one(Some(0)));
    assert_eq!(1, add_one(None));
    assert_eq!(1000, add_one(Some(999)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Namely, how to make compiler know the type of x is not Option anymore?

Rust's type checker doesn't have to be compatible with somewhat dodgy usage patterns, so the way to do that is to redefine x as not an option anymore e.g.:

```rust
fn add_one(mut x: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    let x = if let Some(v) = x {
        v
    } else {
        0
    };
    return x + 1;
}
```

or the uglier and less efficient (but maybe closer to Python):

```rust
fn add_one(mut x: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    let x = if x == None {
        0
    } else {
        x.unwrap()
    };
    return x + 1;
}
```

Note that you don't *have* to shadow `x`, so you could just as well `let y` instead. It would probably be cleaner here.

But as Boiethios pointed out, Rust provides utilities for this sort of use-cases e.g. [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or), [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or), ...