# Magic behind match: no implementation for `&std::option::Option<ListNode> == std::option::Option<_>

Tags: rust, match, ownership

I'm newbie in Rust from Python. This is my 4th day of learning Rust.

After my first question [Type casting for Option type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811196/type-casting-for-option-type), I have a follow up question related to syntax `match` and ownership concept.

---

Firstly, I declare a `ListNode` struct with `new` implementation.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
pub struct ListNode {
  pub val: i32,
}

impl ListNode {
  #[inline]
  fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    ListNode {
      val
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to compare if two nodes are same by comparing the val of node. Here's my ugly implementation.

```rust
fn is_same(a: &Option<ListNode>, b: &Option<ListNode>) -> bool {
    if a == None && b == None { return true; }
    else if a == None && b != None { return false; }
    else if a != None && b == None { return false; }

    let ca: ListNode = a.clone().unwrap_or(ListNode::new(0));
    let cb: ListNode = b.clone().unwrap_or(ListNode::new(0));
    if ca.val == cb.val { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Option<ListNode> = Some(ListNode::new(0));
    let b: Option<ListNode> = Some(ListNode::new(0));
    
    println!("{:?}", is_same(&a, &b));
}
```

Then, I got many errors...

```
no implementation for `&std::option::Option<ListNode> == std::option::Option<_>
```

According to my knowledge of ownership concept, using `*` for borrowed parameter should be optional. But, to make the comparison work, I need to add `*`. Below modified function works. (One additional found is that, using `a.clone()` is fine but `*a.clone()` is wrong with error `` type `ListNode` cannot be dereferenced ``.)

```rust
fn is_same(a: &Option<ListNode>, b: &Option<ListNode>) -> bool {
    if *a == None && *b == None { return true; }
    else if *a == None && *b != None { return false; }
    else if *a != None && *b == None { return false; }

    let ca: ListNode = a.clone().unwrap_or(ListNode::new(0));
    let cb: ListNode = b.clone().unwrap_or(ListNode::new(0));
    if ca.val == cb.val { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

Since above solution code is too ugly, here's another implementation by using `match` without redundant `unwrap_or` and `*`.

```rust
fn is_same(a: &Option<ListNode>, b: &Option<ListNode>) -> bool {
    match (a, b) {
        (None, None) => true,
        (None, _) => false,
        (_, None) => false,
        (Some(a), Some(b)) => a.val == b.val,
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, `a` and `b` are successfully compared with `None` without `*` and `unwrap_or`.

---

Those code ends to below questions:

- Why `*` is needed to compare with None in my original code?
- What is the magic behind `match`? How does this syntax make code skip using `*` and `unwrap_or` for comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `*` is needed to compare with `None` in my original code?

It's not *needed* per-se, but `Eq` is only implemented for identical types, so you need to compare either two `Option<T>` or two `&Option<T>`. From this you might see that [comparing your nodes to `&None` would also have worked](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e25c1825483fd9f4d10a59758ee3a25).

> What is the magic behind match? How does this syntax make code skip using * and unwrap_or for comparison?

[Match Ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md). Basically, `match` will attempt to automatically add references to patterns in order to try and resolve the types.

Also I don't know if you've noticed and just want to work harder, but `Option<T: Eq>` implements `Eq`, so `is_same(&a, &b)` [could just be written `a == b`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=919c6ecdf36a2ab221a6c01b6a109c6e).

And an other thing, `#[inline]` is usually recommended against, it's generally better to avoid providing hints unless you've specifically looked at the generated output and the compiler refuses to yield what you're looking for otherwise. Keep in mind: the code here is so simple that in release mode and even using the complicated version of `is_same` with a bunch of dereferences, llvm finds out what's what and just loads and formats a constant `true`.

Comment: Thanks, RFC is the exact history I want to learn. About "work harder" comment, I didn't notice `==` work in my example code, that code was actually a simplified version of a recursive comparison which was total removed in the example code (simple `==` wouldn't work there surely). Thanks for pointing out that, I will be more careful next time.